# How to reuse View and Edit code with Flask Pluggable Views

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I am following the example code from here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/views/#pluggable-views

I don't think this code is complete, I can't get it to work and build upon it.

I am trying to reuse code for the following functions:

**Adding Database Entries**

```
@app.route('/add/category/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addCategory():
    form = forms.AddCategory()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        database.addCategory(name)
        return redirect('/view/categories/')
    return render_template('add-category.html', form = form)


@app.route('/add/revision/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addRevision():
    form = forms.AddRevision()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        version = form.version.data
        database.addRevision(name, version)
        return redirect('/view/revisions/')
    return render_template('add-revision.html', form = form)
```

**Editing Database Entries**

```
@app.route('/edit/category/<category>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def editCategory(category):
    form = forms.AddCategory()
    form.name.data = category
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        newName = form.name.data
        database.editCategory(name = category, newName = newName)
        #view single category?
        return redirect('/view/categories/')
    return render_template('edit-category.html', category = category, form = form)

@app.route('/edit/revision/<name>/<version>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def editRevision(name, version):
    form = forms.AddRevision()
    form.name.data = name
    form.version.data = version
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        newName = form.name.data
        newVersion = form.version.data
        database.editRevision(name, version, newName, newVersion)
        return redirect('/view/revisions/')
    return render_template('edit-revision.html', name = name, version = version, form = form)
```

This is my current code

```
class ListView(View):
    def get_template_name(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
    def render_template(self, context):
        return render_template(self.get_template_name(), **context)
    def dispatch_request(self):
        context = {'objects': self.get_objects()}
        return self.render_template(context)

class CategoryView(ListView):
    def get_template_name(self):
        return 'categories.html'
    def get_objects(self):
        return models.Category.query.all()

app.add_url_rule('/categories', view_func=RenderTemplateView.as_view('categories', template_name='categories.html'))
```

Where do I specify to use the CategoryView class in the app.add_url_rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the docs switch context between those two code blocks - the second set of examples using `RenderTemplateView` are not meant to "go with" the previous entries sketching `ListView`.

```
app.add_url_rule('/categories', view_func=RenderTemplateView  # ... snip ...
```

should be:

```
app.add_url_rule('/categories', view_func=CategoryView.as_view("category"))
```

That [creates a function](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/bb99158c870a2d761f1349af02ef1decf0d10c7b/flask/views.py#L72) which, when called will create an instance of your `CategoryView` and call its [`dispatch_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.views.View.dispatch_request) method.